# Docker-compose файл для базы данных

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Я новичок в `Docker`. Подскажите, как мне настроить, что б `PostgreSQL` в доккере имел свой `volume` на физческом диске для БД, что б при перезагрузке данные не обнулялись.  И как пути писать, если мой компьютер на `Windows` и путь к БД, скажем, `C:\myPath\Pstgres\Data\` , а сервер на `linux`, и там база будет лежать, скажем, в `var\lib\postgres\data` ?
И при этом, что б я мог зайти со стороннего IDE и посмотреть базу. Т.е. что б это была не полностью внутренняя закрытая сеть, на сколько я понимаю.
Как написать docker-compose файл для такой задачи?
Спасибо

Comment: 1) В своём docker-compose файле не создавай `volume`, а пометь что он будет `external: true`. Естественно, эти `volume` надо будет создать заранее с разными настройками на Виндвос и Линукс https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external

2) Доступ к базе извне вообще базовая функциональность. Какой порт прокинещь наружу, по такому и будет доступна. Имя хоста, разумеется, будет именем хоста, на котором крутится докер.

Answer (score 1):

например так:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: database
    hostname: database
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myuser
      - POSTGRES_USER=mystrongsecret
    restart: always
```

При этом сам сервер баз данных будет доступен на ip сервера, на котором развернут и на порту 5432

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас задача только с одним образом работать, использование композитора это оверкил.

*1191130.mk*

```
# File      : 1191130.mk
# Modified  : <2020-10-31 Sat 19:15:09 GMT>
# URL       : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191130

PG_VERSION ?= 12
PG_PORt ?= 5432

.PHONY: all

all: run-pg

run-pg:
    $(info Starting up PostgreSQL v$(PG_VERSION) on localhost:$(PG_PORT))
    docker rm --force pg || true
    docker run \
    --detach \
    --env "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" \
    --env "POSTGRES_USER=username" \
    --name pg \
    --publish $(PG_PORT):$(PG_PORT) \
    --volume "/path/on/your/host/machine:/var/lib/postgresql/data" \
    postgres:$(PG_VERSION)

# End 1191130.mk
```

**Ссылки**

- https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/